# Download h-index time series from Scopus or Orcid

Tags: bibliography, scopus, pybliometrics, orcid

Starting from the Scopus ID of a scientist, how can I retrieve the time series of his h-index?

That is, how do I get the h-index as a function of time?

I need to do that in an automatic way, in Python, using the Scopus API (or a wrapper like pybliometrics), or any other API.

I can also use Orcid for this, since I can get the Orcid ID from the Scopus ID.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, Scopus does not provide a timeseries of the h-index; overall, all information through the Author Retrieval shows exactly the latest state.

You would have to compute the h-index for each year on your own:

1. Retrieve full publication list for an author via Scopus Search API
2. For each publication, retrieve yearly citaton via Citation Overview API
3. Combine all citations so that citations from the same year sum up
4. Compute the h-index for each year